# How to compute $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^TMx}$ efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $M$ be a real symmetric integer valued positive definite matrix with $\det(M) \geq 1$. I would like write code to compute

$$S_M= \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^TMx}.$$

One option is to simply iterate over the vectors $x$ starting with ones with small coefficients and stop if things seem to be converging. Apart from the obvious problem of determining when to stop, this method is tremendously slow if $M$ is even $10$ by $10$.

It is tempting to look at the integral $\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} e^{-x^TMx}\;dx$ instead but this equals $\sqrt{\frac{\pi^n}{\det(M)}}$ which is potentially a terrible approximation (it can for example be much less than $1$ where $S_M \geq 1$).

> How can one compute a good approximation for $S_M$?  Even an algorithm
>   that runs $2^n$ time would be a huge improvement over what I have
>   currently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to compute a multi-dimensional theta function, and this question is studied in depth in [this 2003 Math. Comp. article by Deconinck, Heil, Bobenko, van Hoeij,and Schmies](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-247/S0025-5718-03-01609-0/S0025-5718-03-01609-0.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for this. Please excuse my ignorance but would you be able explicitly to show an example?  The Riemann theta function seems to require that $Im(\Omega)$ is strictly positive definite but my matrix $M$ is real. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64261/whats-the-difference-between-a-riemann-theta-and-a-siegel-theta-function shows that there is a Maple function `RiemannTheta`. How would you use it in my case?  Or equivalently, how would you use the Mathematica function `SiegelTheta`?

Comment: In your case, $S_M = \Theta\left(0 \vert \tfrac{1}{\pi} i M\right)$, where $\tfrac{1}{\pi} i M$ is indeed complex symmetric with strictly positive definite imaginary part.

Comment: For anyone interested, I tried the code as implemented at https://github.com/abelfunctions/abelfunctions/wiki/Getting%20Started and it is very slow. About 10 seconds for a 9 by 9 matrix and too slow to compute for a 12 by 12 matrix. I don't know if the version implemented by Mathematica is much faster as I don't have access to it.

Comment: @Lembik what was the exact code you ran?

Comment: It was essentially identical to the code at https://github.com/abelfunctions/abelfunctions/issues/121 .

Comment: @Lembik If you read the paper, you will see that the radius GROWS with $g$ (which is basically the dimension), and since the number of evaluations is something like $R^g,$ the running time will be superexponential. Presumably this cannot really be helped.

Comment: This is a shame as you can naively approximate the sum from below by only looking at vectors $x$ with small coefficients (say -$x_i \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$).  This seems to run in roughly the same amount of time and be accurate to within a few decimal places. In other words, it appears the naive approach is almost as good.

Comment: @Lembik I think that might be partly due to a desire on their part to get provable bounds...